# Texturing a square in OpenGL ES on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

Alright, so I've got this OpenGL tutorial I'm basing from, my current code is equivalent to Part II of it, which is here:
http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/04/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-ii-building-a-polygon/

The code for that can be downloaded near the bottom of the page.  It leaves you with a white square, and I want to apply a texture to it, which this tutorial series doesn't cover.  I can't figure out how to texture my white square, in Android.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at this: http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/

It is a tutorial exactly on that.

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](https://github.com/learnopengles/Learn-OpenGLES-Tutorials) set has been very helpful for me getting acquainted with OpenGL ES 2.0. For simple texturing in particular, **see lesson #4**.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at lesson 7 here:
http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/